# Save number from user input and get average

Tags: python, user-input

2.7.x

```
 rate = raw_input('Rating: ')
```

How would you go about saving each number and at the end getting the average?
Before that line of code, it's:

```
for i in range(n):
```

Much appreciated.

Edit:

After tweaking with the code, I got this:

```
  L = []

for i in range(n):

    line = raw_input('Next Track: ')
    m = L.append(raw_input('Rating: '))
    overall = sum(map(int, L)) / len(L)

    f.write("Track Name: " + line + " - Rating: " + str(m) + "\n")
f.close()

f = open('music.txt','a')



print "Overall Rating: ", overall


f = open("music.txt", 'a')
f.write("Overall Rating: " + str(overall) + "\n")
f.write("---------------------------\n")
f.close
```

Now, the problem is, whenever I enter a number for rating, it comes back as "None" on the file. Why?

Comment: `list.append` returns `None`, don't try and save the result of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the values to a list:

```
L = []
for i in range(n):
    L.append(raw_input('Rating: '))
```

Then, you can get the average of the list:

```
sum(map(int, L)) / len(l)
```

Or, you can use a list comprehension:

```
L = [int(raw_input('Rating: ')) for _ in range(n)]
sum(L) / len(L)
```

---

However, if you're dealing with floats, then use this to get the average:

```
from __future__ import division
sum(L) / len(L)
```

`from __future__ import division` changes the `/` to a true division operator. True division is active in python 3, but as you are on python 2.7, you can import it directly.

---

With your code, there are some problems:

`L.append(raw_input('Rating: '))` returns `None`. You don't need to assign it to a variable, so get rid of the `m =`.

However, it seems you want to keep the value of `m` so you can write it in the file. You can then do something like:

```
m = raw_input("Rating: ")
L.append(m)
```

There is also no need for `str(m)`, as `raw_input()` returns a string.

---

And finally, you should use the `with` statement when opening files. This saves calling `close()`:

```
with open('music.txt','a') as f:
    for i in range(n):
        line = raw_input('Next Track: ')
        m = raw_input("Rating: ")
        L.append(m)
        overall = sum(map(int, L)) / len(L)
        f.write("Track Name: " + line + " - Rating: " + m + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me tons of frustration :P

Comment: @BrianFuller No problem :). Also, sorry for the kinda long answer lol :p

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average) to do this in a single pass:

```
>>> avg = 0.0
>>> for i in range(3):
        avg = (avg * i + float(raw_input('Rating: '))) / (i + 1)


Rating: 3
Rating: 5
Rating: 7
>>> avg
5.0
```

But this would only be useful if you didn't already know what `n` is equal to, in your case I would do this:

```
>>> avg, n = 0.0, 3
>>> for i in range(n):
        avg += float(raw_input('Rating: '))


Rating: 3
Rating: 5
Rating: 7
>>> avg /= n
>>> avg
5.0
```